# Unable to Understand this Flutter Closure Function Code?

Tags: flutter, loops, dart

```
var callbacks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  callbacks.add(() => print(i));
}
callbacks.forEach((c) => c());
```

I dont Understand Two Things :

1. print(i) is of return-type Void, shouldnt the compiler show "error", because the work of print(i) is to print the item to the console and not return something.
2. in the line " callbacks.forEach((c) => c()); " how come c() became a function, because it was a parameter inside the lambda function to get values.

the link of the Code :
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators
under for Loops

PS : I am a beginner to this syntax, so Thank you so much for your Help Guys !

Comment: is the value of i of specific type always stored in the list , callbacks list - [print(0), print(1)], and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
var callbacks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  callbacks.add(() => print(i));
}
callbacks.forEach((c) => c());
```

Here, `() => print(i)` is a closure which takes no arguments and returns `void`. In the loop, you add these functions to the `callback` list.

`(c) => c()` is a closure which takes a `dynamic` parameter and attempts to call it (i.e. calls `c.call()`).

Some type safety might be helpful here, for example:

```dart
final callbacks = <void Function()>[];  // an empty list of functions that look like () -> void
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  final void Function() callback = () => print(i);
  callbacks.add(callback);
}
callbacks.forEach((void Function() callback) => callback());
```

In this example, because `callbacks` has a type of `List<void Function()>`, the parameter of the function passed to `forEach` is a `void Function()`, which means you can call it with `c()`